# Sync all RealtimeDB data to the Google's sheet columns

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For every time im adding, or editing a product through my app, I am trying to write Firebase RealtimeDB data into a Google Sheets spreadsheet through Google Appscript.

This is what my RealtimeDB looks like

[image]

And this is my goal for every product (ignore the blue box)

[image]

This is what i have done so far but i do not know how to handle the sheet ranges and add the data in those specific positions.

```
url="https://inventory-c1e.firebaseio.com/Items.json?&auh=pur6Ka8wYVAd" 
xpath="OMCPC150C/itembarcode"   //here im trying something but dont know how to continue for all DB values      
function addProduct() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([IMPORTJSON()]);
}
function IMPORTJSON(){
  
  try{
    
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    //Logger.log(typeof(json));
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
  
}
```

So please kindly guide me on how to continue